# Is the imperfective subjunctive "jouât" mandatory in this "À moins que ..." clause?

Tags: temps-grammatical, subjonctif

> Elle a connu un succès fulgurant. Enfant, je jouais souvent avec elle, vous savez ! À moins qu’elle ne se **jouât** déjà de moi, à l’époque...

I was translating some colloquial sentences into French, and I'm wondering if the use of the imperfective subjunctive "jouât" is mandatory in this particular instance.

Context: A man is reminiscing about the good old days when his niece, a business prodigy, was still just a little girl.

Comment: Especially in colloquial language, I tend to avoid using the imperfective subjunctive in favour of the present tense, even when a verb obviously refers to a past action, as in: "*Je les ai pris pour les gens les plus généreux du monde... jusqu’à ce qu’ils me **disent** qu’ils ne me paieraient pas vu qu’ils me nourrissaient !*"

Comment: Beware that *Enfant, je jouais souvent...* will be understood as "When **I** was a child, I was often playing..." which is not what you want to say.

Comment: The imperfective subjunctive is **never** mandatory. I don't know how to conjugate it (like many French speakers) and I've never used it non-ironically in a spoken sentence. You might very well be better are conjugating that tense than me.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat How do you paraphrase the last sentence yourself?

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens Well I'm not 100% sure what you mean, it's one of those "idiomatic uncanny valley" translation. They're grammatically correct, but not idiomatic, and I don't even know how I'd say it cause it's hard to tell exactly what you meant. *se jouer de qqn* is **not** colloquial, and I'm sure what a child that *se joue d'un adulte* would be doing. Was she using you? Deceiving you? Making fun of you? I think you should rephrase it for me to make a,version, or add the English version.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Hi. This is a translation of a colloquial English sentence said by an old man, so I went for a rather *stiff* construction. As for what this girl was like as a kid, yes, the old man suspects she might have been a cunning girl, taking advantage of adults around her. So what he said boils down to: "I thought I was innocently playing with her, but I might well have been the one who was being *played*". {with a negative connotation of manipulation, deception}

Comment: Oh ok that makes sens. Then I'd say "*Mais peut-être qu'elle se jouait déjà de moi à l'époque*". You don't need to use the subjunctive at all actually, I don't think *À moins que* is the most fitting here.

Answer (score 3):

#### Does it have to be the imperfect of the subjunctive?

Not mandatory, but still sounding quite well, at least when my eyes are hearing it...

It’s easy enough to avoid it:

- Mais peut-être se **jouait-elle** déjà de moi, à l’époque...

Further down is a quick, totally unscientific, but nevertheless real-life test that suggest this might well be your best bet if you want to mimic the real-life day-to-day contemporary oral use of French.

---

#### What if we want to preserve the subjunctive?

Keeping the subjunctive is a bit harder. The present tense is totally out of question because of the introduction with *“à moins que”*, which demands the past in this context. Since the imperfect of the subjunctive is so scarce in today’s speech habits of French speakers, and since there’s a clear need for a past tense here, people would tend to re-invent a conjugation of the imperfect of the subjunctive in order to maintain the past rather than switch to the easier present tense of the subjunctive, like it’s commonly being done in other contexts.

The structure remains that of the subjunctive, since it occurs in a context where the subjunctive would always show up, were the sentence to be in the present tense<sup>1</sup>. But it tends to mimic the conjugation of the indicative for some persons, including the third singular person in this case.

→ **N.B.** Obviously, this is unlikely to be recommended by any serious grammatician, but it will *“sound”* better than the present of the subjunctive:

- À moins qu’elle (ne) se **jouait** déjà de moi, à l’époque...

To illustrate an example where the conjugation may differ from the indicative, let’s switch to the second plural person. In this case, I, Montée de lait, would tend to say something like the following (99% of the time without the *“ne”*, but this is [another subject](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/14020/13100) altogether):

- À moins que vous (ne) vous **jouiiez** déjà de moi, à l’époque.

This conjugation is [not to be found](https://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/conjugaison/verbe/jouer.html) in textbooks (they’d rather recommend *que vous ne vous jouassiez* in this case, but this conjugation has grown pretty much foreign to today’s spoken French). However, the presence of an added *“i”* and the extended pronunciation it triggers makes it feels like a past tense, and differenciates it from the subjunctive present *(que vous ne jouiez)*.

#### How well would that new type of conjugation pass with real people?

I tested around me with ***boire*** and the second plural person, and everybody in my sample said they would rephrase for lack of knowing how to conjugate the verb at that point. Their answers kept “à moins que”, but were otherwise rather longer and using a conjugation of the indicative mode:

- À moins que vous aviez déjà commencé à boire à l’époque.

When asked to comment on my answer of it, *“À moins que vous buviiez déjà à l’époque”*, they all said they wouldn’t have come up with it, most said they probably wouldn’t use it in the future, but that it did have a clear past tense feeling to it and was quite easily understandable.

#### So use with caution...

---

1. <sub>Je modifie le verbe utilisé pour bien montrer le subjonctif, la conjugaison du verbe *jouer* étant la même au présent de l’indicatif et du subjonctif pour la troisième personne du singulier :</sub>

   - <sub>À moins qu’elle ne se **dise** déjà de moi que je suis bien naïf.</sub>

---

#### Extras

Je ne voulais pas trop m’attarder sur le sujet, parce que la question est légitime. Elle concerne une tournure appelant normalement un subjonctif imparfait et le contexte est accessoire, il a pour but d’illustrer d’où surgit la question.

<sub>Mais on a en commentaires mentionné quelques faiblesses de l’exemple. Elles sont possiblement réelles et je leur donne ce petit espace:</sub>

- <sub>**Enfant**, je jouais souvent avec elle. → Ce n’est pas *elle* mais *je* qui était alors enfant, ce qui n’est possiblement pas le but.</sub>

  - <sub>The OP was actually caught a bit by surprise with this one (see below in the comments). There are ways around, but they may not work in the bigger picture (which we don’t have):</sub>
    <sub>*Enfant, elle venait souvent jouer avec moi.*</sub>
    <sub>*Quand elle n’était qu’une petite fille, je jouais souvent avec elle.*</sub>
- <sub>**Se jouer de quelqu’un** est assez rarement positif, et assume tout un moins un masque : au mieux, elle ne prenait qu’un intérêt de façade au jeu ou faignait d’être plus naïve qu’elle ne l’était pour endormir la méfiance et remporter les enjeux importants.</sub>

  - <sub>This point is clarified in comments by the OP. There is indeed a will to emphasize her manipulative mind.</sub>

Comment: In the sentence I added to the comment: "*... jusqu’à ce qu’ils me **disent** qu’ils ne me **paieraient** pas vu qu’ils me **nourrissaient** !*", I have no qualms about using the present "disent", as it is followed by two other verbs signalling that it concerns a past action. Which is why, I think, I don't feel too comfortable with the *standalone* present: "*À moins qu’elle se **joue** déjà de moi, à l’époque...*".

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens I believe the context “à moins que (...) déjà”, combined with something in the past, just makes the present tense sound really bad, whereas “jusqu’à ce que” is more common in the “wrong” tense and supports a switch to the present better (also, the requirement for subjunctive feels stronger, to me at least).

Comment: *À moins qu’elle ne se soit déjà jouée de moi, à l’époque...*

Comment: @jlliagre In which case, the act of "manipulating" only happened on a single occasion. To make it sound more like a continuing action in the past, how do you paraphrase it?

Comment: I feel the nuance, but doesn't the presence of *déjà* kind of imply that wasn't on a single occasion?

Comment: @jlliagre This is not an easy sentence, and perhaps my answer is a bit simplistic, but I feel that *“se jouer de moi”* here is a continuous or at least semi-continuous action, while what you're mentionning *(qu’elle se soit déjà joué de moi)* is a bit more of a one-time event that drags in time and extends in the future. Close to what the OP answered you, actually.

Comment: The negative connotation of "se jouer de" was what I actually needed in this sentence to convey the manipulative side of her, even as a kid. I used it intentionally in stark contrast with the positive "jouer avec". As for "enfant", on the other hand, it looks like it doesn't work the way I'd hoped. Thanks.

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens Nice to hear back. Lack of the full context made it a little unexpected, but given what you're mentioning now, I guess the big picture would be clear enough.

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens Actually, it is actually even more complex than I thought. There's a chance people don't switch to the indicative mode, but rather re-invent the imperfect of the subjunctive. I think my answer needs a deep revision.

Comment: Hi. I just added a comment under my question.

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens Here it the revised version. Probably not final, but my take on it is surely evolving with time.

Comment: Am I the only one to be shocked by your proposal of indicative *"A moins qu'elle ne se jouait de moi à l'époque..."? It sounds really odd to my ears, more than the present subjunctive in that case. "À moins qu’elle se joue déjà de moi, à l’époque...". The notion of past is still carried by the 'A l'époque". To me, the present here would implie that it's still true today.

Comment: @XouDo I'll stick to my guns right now, but perhaps it is a very personal point of view that the imperfect sounds better than the present. And I still think the present sounds odd. But perhaps I don't communicate enough to have a taste that would be representative of that of the majority.