# Personne n'a faim vs personne a faim

Tags: négation, formulation-idiomatique

Je comprends pas la logique dans la phrase "personne n'a faim" qui, à mon avis, signifie d'une part "personne" donc le contraire de tout le monde et d'autre part "n'a faim" donc pas faim qui donc, pour moi, se comprend comme "un ensemble vide de personne a pas faim" qui implicitement signifie que les personnes restantes (le complémentaire de l'ensemble vide) ont faim.

Je peine à comprendre la logique dans cette grammaire.

Comment: [Omission of “ne” in “ne … personne”](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14020/omission-of-ne-in-ne-personne)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Personne* n'a le plus souvent de valeur négative que lorsqu'il est accompagné d'un *ne* ou employé seul (*Qui est venu ? Personne*).

Par exemple dans la phrase :

> Personne n'a tué personne.

le premier *personne* est négatif et correspond à *no one/nobody* alors que le deuxième *personne* ne l'est le plus souvent pas et correspond à *anyone/anybody*.

Dans *personne n'a faim*, il n'y a pas de double négation et le sens est bien celui de *nobody is hungry*. Pour obtenir la phrase de ton raisonnement, il faudrait une vraie double négation :

> *Personne n'a pas faim → Tout le monde a faim.

À l'oral, le *ne* disparaît<sup>1</sup> le plus souvent pour donner :

> Personne a faim.

Pour aller plus loin: [*L'expression de la négation dans les langues romanes*, Francis Corblin, 2003](http://fcorblin.free.fr/textes/Copie%20de%20negConcRomance.pdf).

<sup>1</sup><sub>Ce n'est pas spécifique à ce cas précis. En dehors du registre soutenu, les *ne* disparaissent à l'oral: *j'ai pas faim* au lieu de *je n'ai pas faim*.</sub>

Comment: You might want to change your example *Personne ne parle à personne* to discuss this issue. It has two opposite meanings: 1) nobody is speaking to anyone ; 2) everyone has to speak to someone...

Comment: @GAMPUB Bien vu, je n'avais pas pensé à ce sens. Pas sûr que ma nouvelle préposition n'ait pas aussi cette faille...

Comment: effectivement, c'est pareil pour la nouvelle *proposition*.

Comment: @GAMPUB Oui. Disons que la deuxième interprétation est statistiquement plus rare avec *tuer* mais j'ai tempéré mon affirmation pour tenir compte de ce cas.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't translate it word for word, **Personne n'a faim** means nobody is hungry.
Personne is the negative form (négation) of tout(s) le monde. By this logic if you try to find the opposite of **tout le monde a faim**, you'll get **personne n'a faim**.

Answer (score -3):

La particule « ne » dont il s'agit dans cette phrase est le « *ne explétif* », c'est à dire un mot qui n'apporte pas de modification de sens, soit qu'il soit enlevé, soit qu'il soit ajouté ([réf.](http://www.bertrandboutin.ca/Folder_151_Grammaire/O_a_la_negation.htm#_le_ne_expl%C3%A9tif)). Il existe des théories variées mais difficiles à aborder en explication de la persistance de cet usage ([réf.](https://www.lesoir.be/art/1511453/article/debats/chroniques/vous-avez-ces-mots/2017-05-26/ne-expletif-d-autant-plus-beau-qu-il-est-inutile)).

> Mais pourquoi ce ne explétif se maintient-il, s’il n’assume aucune fonction ? Les grammairiens avancent plusieurs hypothèses. La plupart s’appuient sur l’association entre le ne explétif et le subjonctif, mode commenté dans cette chronique, le 18 février dernier, et qui exprime une virtualité, une distance vis-à-vis du réel.

À la section 756 du *Bon Usage* (14ième édition) on trouve des informations sur l'emploi de « personne ». On y trouve la confirmation que dans la langue littéraire encore lue de nos jours, « personne » ne signifie pas nécessairement « pas une personne » mais en fait tout simplement ce que le mot exprime, plus ou moins précisément cependant. (italique entre crochets et caractères gras dus à user LPH)

> Emplois de personne
> a) Conformément à son origine, personne peut encore avoir un sens positif, « **quelqu'un** » « **n'importe qui** », mais dans des conditions particulières
> qui lui sont communes avec d'autres auxiliaires de négation (§ 1021)
>
> - Ils connaissaient mieux que PERSONNE les passages dans les bois (STENDHAL,
>   Chartr., V). [*n'importe qui*]
> - Nous y serions [...] avant que PERSONNE pût savoir où nous
>   aurions fui ce monde (BALZAC, Béatrix, Pl., p. 271).
>   [*qui que ce soit, n'importe qui*]
> - Elle cherchait le sucrier sans flambeau, de peur de réveiller PERSONNE (BARBEY D'AUR., Diabol.,Pl.,p. 49).
>   [*quelqu'un*]
> - Devant sa [= de Saussure] grâce aristocratique et jeune, on ne pouvait imaginer que PERSONNE reproche à la linguistique de manquer de vie (A. MEILLET,
>   Ling. histor. et ling. gén., t. II, p. 179).
>   [*quelqu'un, qui que ce soit*]
>
> b) Dans l'usage ordinaire, personne s'emploie dans un contexte explicitement négatif, soit dans la dépendance de **sans, sans que**, soit comme **auxiliaire de l'adverbe ne**.
>
> - Un vieil écrivain nous a quittés sur la pointe des pieds, sans que
>   presque PERSONNE y prête attention (MAURIAC, dans le Figaro litt., 14-23 juin
>   1968).
>   [*remarquer que « ne » n'est pas utilisé lorsque « personne » est utilisé avec « sans que »*]
> - PERSONNE ne sera assez hardi pour le faire (Ac. 1935).
>   c)
>   Comme d'autres auxiliaires de la négation (§ 1022), « personne » a pris
>   par contagion le sens négatif de l'adverbe « ne » qu'il accompagne d'ordinaire.
>
> N. B. On ne peut plus dire "PERSONNE n'est PAS venu. Cf. § 1019, b.